# How to use extensions

Tags: premake

Could someone please explain how one uses the premake extensions. I added the eclipse extension in a directory under my premake installation. And in the premake script I added `recuire "eclipse"`.

Running the script with `premake5 eclipse`, I get an error `module "eclipse.lua" not found`.

I added the path of the modules directory to my environment variables.

I'm using premake (premake5) on Windows 8.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working by adding the full path to the `require` statement.

`require "C:/premake/eclipse/eclipse"`

and running the command as `premake5 eclipse`

**Note:** This plugin does not generate project files that one can import into Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

addons need to reside in a folder. You need to create a "eclipse" folder, then copy all the files in it, and the "eclipse" folder should be located where premake can load it (either next the executable or some other place handled through environment variables)

Comment: The premake-core wiki has [a page on locating files](https://github.com/premake/premake-core/wiki/Locating_Scripts) which shows how to set up the search paths so you don't have to use a absolute path.